# compare and diff between jade template and mustache template

Tags: node.js, pug, mustache, mean

i am beginner in java script and familiar with client developing in low level.
my question is this that what main diff between **jade** template engine and **mustache** template?
both of them is for **nodejs** server side or use in client side?
what advantage of each in their scope ?

if i want to write small single page app in **MEAN stack** structure in this case choose of which template syntax is best ? html 5? jade? mustache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to use Jade especially for the **NodeJS** apps on the backend side given it integrates well with Node.js and provides a light syntax.

and I use MustacheJS for when I want to use templating within html.

Here is more information on Jade and MustacheJS.

- https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-javascript-templates-jade-mustache-dust/
- http://jster.net/blog/templating-javascript-mustache-jade-transparency#.V0mrXZN96Rs
- http://vschart.com/compare/mustache-template-language/vs/jade-template-engin